# Linear algebra: $Ax=b$, proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a matrix, $b$ is a vector. Show that if the equation $Ax = b$ has two distinct solutions, then it has infinitely many solutions.

Can someone help me with this through clear explanations?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are two distinct solutions.
Then so are $(1-\lambda)x+\lambda y$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ because
$$A((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y) = (1-\lambda)Ax+\lambda Ay = (1-\lambda)b+\lambda b = b.$$
Hence the entire line through $x$ and $y$ solves also the given linear system. This line contains infinitely many points because $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ and $y$ are both distinct solutions then,

$Ax = b$ and $Ay = b$,

then

$Ax + Ay = A(x + y) = 2b$,

so $\frac12 (x + y)$ is a solution as well.

Comment: well, technically you only argue why the existence  of two solutions implies the existence of a third solution

Comment: That's true, you would have to extrapolate to show that the third solution implies a fourth solution, etc.

Comment: I know, I only thought you could clarify this in your answer :)

Comment: I'll just upvote the other answer instead

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax_1=Ax_2=b$ and $x_1 \ne x_2$ then put

$z_t=t(x_1-x_2)+x_1$ for $t \in \mathbb K$.

Then $Az_t=b$ for all $t \in \mathbb K$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ has at least two solutions, say $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$, with $\mathbf{x}_1 \neq \mathbf{x}_2$.

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Denote by $\mathbf{x}_0$ the difference $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$; so $\mathbf{x}_0 \neq \mathbf{0}$. Then
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A(\mathbf{x}_1 + t \mathbf{x}_0)
&=
A\mathbf{x}_1 + A(t \mathbf{x}_0) 
&\qquad
&
\\
&= \mathbf{b} + t(A \mathbf{x}_0)
&\qquad
&\text{($\mathbf{x}_1$ is a solution)}
\\
&= \mathbf{b} + t\bigl(A (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1) \bigr)
&\qquad
&
\\
&= \mathbf{b} + t (A \mathbf{x}_2 - A \mathbf{x}_1)
&\qquad
&
\\
&= \mathbf{b} + t(\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b})
&\qquad
&\text{($\mathbf{x}_1$, $\mathbf{x}_2$ are solutions)}
\\
&= \mathbf{b}.
&\qquad
&
\end{alignat*}
Thus, $\mathbf{x}_1 + t \mathbf{x}_0$ is a solution. Since $t$ was arbitrary (it can take on infinitely many values) and $\mathbf{x}_0 \neq \mathbf{0}$, the solution set of $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ includes the *infinite* set $\{ \mathbf{x}_1 + t \mathbf{x}_0 \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Therefore, there are infinitely many solutions.